# How to load JNDI context from the file system into Spring?

Tags: java, spring, datasource, jndi

I ran the following code:

```
    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String,String>();

    environment.put( Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory");
    environment.put( Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/C:/Users" ); 

    Context context = new InitialContext( environment );
    context.rebind("John",  new Person("John", "Smith", 35, 'm'));
```

(`Person` is a `javax.naming.Referenceable` object), which generated a `.bindings` file:

```
#This file is used by the JNDI FSContext.
#Sun Jan 14 13:50:02 EST 2018
John/RefAddr/3/Content=m
John/ClassName=com.examples.jndi.Person
John/RefAddr/1/Type=lastName
John/RefAddr/1/Content=Smith
John/RefAddr/3/Encoding=String
John/RefAddr/1/Encoding=String
John/RefAddr/2/Type=age
John/RefAddr/2/Content=35
John/RefAddr/3/Type=gender
John/RefAddr/2/Encoding=String
John/RefAddr/0/Content=John
John/RefAddr/0/Type=firstName
John/RefAddr/0/Encoding=String
```

How do I use Spring to load up this context from the file system ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` as below?

```
<bean id="jndi" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
   <property name="jndiEnvironment">
     <props>
       <prop key="java.naming.factory.initial">com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory</prop>
       <prop key="java.naming.provider.url">file:/C:/Users</prop>
     </props>
   </property>
   ...
 </bean>
```